# How can I change the inline attribute checked="checked" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a move up/move down function on one of my lists and the things I need to move contain checkboxes. However, I set the checked attribute in PHP and when I switch the innerHTML of the elements, the checked status always reverts to what the checked attribute is set. I tried making an onchange function to change the attribute as I click it with

```
if(el.checked == true)
    el.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
else
    el.setAttribute("checked", "");
```

but that doesn't work (and i don't know why I even expected it to work, to be honest)

Any idea how I could do it? Switching the elements alltogether in the dom tree would be problematic as would be not setting the checked attribute in PHP.

edit: aparently there's no way to do what I asked but my problem is fixed by not being a lazy bastard and moving things around in the DOM like i'm suppsoed to.

Comment: Tried `('checked',false)` and `('checked',true)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `checked` attribute is present in HTML (no matter what value it has), then the IDL (DOM) attribute `checked` is initialized to `true`, as opposite to its default value `false`. Your code seems to expect otherwise. I don’t understand what you are trying to do, since you should be able to move a checkbox element withouh such operations. If you move the element node, there is no need to play with the attributes.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid moving the element node and resort to innerHTML switches but it seems i'll have no choice. Either that or set the default checked value in javascript after loading the window.

Comment: I don’t know why you would not just operate on element nodes, but even if you use `innerHTML`, can’t you just HTML code that contains the `checked` attribute? If not, then you can set the `input` element node attribute `checked` to `true` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Set the checked property:

```
checkboxObject.checked=true|false
```

You can try this way

```
if(true) document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
else document.getElementById("check1").checked = false;
```

Check on [w3School.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_checked)

Hope this resolves your issue.